# OOP - Memory Usage and Large Math Objects (Classes)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, oop, class

I am starting to move many large non-OOP subroutines that involve expensive iterative math routines into their own class. Whenever I want to use one of the larger subroutines (which are now classes) I create them as an object, assuming that once the object is no longer used (since the calling code is exited) they will be removed form memory.

My question is: If an object is instantiated using say a button or triggering subroutine and the code in that routine is run, will that object get killed from memory via garbage collection once the code is completed?

Also, I don't want to multithread since the user won't be running more than one class at a time.

Comment: The garbage collector runs when it needs to run, not when a method ends.  This is well covered by any introductory book about .NET programming, be sure to check one out from your local library.

Comment: You might want to specify what you mean with "large subroutine". A method with several hundred lines of source code or a method that uses  a lot of memory (for large arrays, memorystreams, whatever). Also you might want to be more specific, how YOU define "large".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will that object get killed from memory via garbage collection once the code is completed?

No, not necessarily.

As soon as that code completes, there will be no more active references to the object.  That means that it will then be *eligible* for garbage collection, but this doesn't happen immediately.  It will get collected at some appropriate time after that point.